# Receiving CommandParameter Value in MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, parameters, commandbinding

I am binding my command like:

```
<Button Command="{Binding NextCommand}" 
    CommandParameter="Hello" 
    Content="Next" />
```

Here, I also bind its CommandParameter property, now how to fetch its value from NextCommand.

```
public ICommand NextCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_nextCommand == null)
            {
                _nextCommand = new RelayCommand(
                    param => this.DisplayNextPageRecords()
                    //param => true
                    );
            }
            return _nextCommand;
        }
    }
```

Its function  definition:

```
public ObservableCollection<PhonesViewModel> DisplayNextPageRecords()
    {

            //How to fetch CommandParameter value which is set by 
            //value "Hello" at xaml. I want here "Hello"
            PageNumber++;
            CreatePhones();
            return this.AllPhones;

    }
```

How to fetch CommandParameter value?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 33):

Change your method definition:

```
public ObservableCollection<PhonesViewModel> DisplayNextPageRecords(object o)
{
    // the method's parameter "o" now contains "Hello"
    PageNumber++;
    CreatePhones();
    return this.AllPhones;
}
```

See how when you create your RelayCommand, its "Execute" lambda takes a parameter? Pass that into your method:

```
_nextCommand = new RelayCommand(param => this.DisplayNextPageRecords(param));
```

Comment: and then you can use like `_nextCommand = new RelayCommand(this.DisplayNextPageRecords);`